# Firebase9 cloud storage [Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Property 'storage' doesn't exist]

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I'm getting the following error:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Invariant Violation: Failed to construct `File`: Must pass both `parts` and `name` arguments.]

I am trying to upload the picture to Firebase cloud storage by choosing the picture on the phone. trying to pass the URI look like:
`file:///Users/miamiamia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CEC7A0BD-01C0-4929-8CF7-74A7FE34293D/data/Containers/Data/Application/C49F3C42-E858-4612-8088-E578FCABA4D6/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540miamiamia%252Fagain/ImagePicker/164BF9DA-8A20-4C97-A892-CB5A1BB4643D.jpg`

What am I doing wrong? I am using reactnative

```
const handleButtonPress = async() => {
    const result =  await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
    });
    setImageUri(result.assets[0].uri)
    console.log(imageUri)
    const { uri } = result.assets[0].uri;
    // const storageRef = storage.ref();
    // const imageRef = storageRef.child('images/image.jpg');
    const storageRef = ref(storage, "path/to/image.jpg")
    const file = new File([""], uri);
    const uploadTask = putFile(storageRef, file)
    uploadTask.then((snapshot) => {
      console.log("Uploaded a blob or file!");
      const downloadURL = getDownloadURL(storageRef);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to request for base64 string from [ImagePicker](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/). You can pass `base64: true` besides `mediaTypes` as [options](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#imagepickeroptions) to get the result in base64 string and you can then use the firebase [upload from string](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_string) method to upload the file

```
const result =  await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
   mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
   base64: true, //<-- boolean base64
});
```

And from `result.assests[0]` you can get

```
{
  "uri": "file:///Users/miamiamia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.....jpg",
  "base64": "data:image/jpeg;base64..."
}
```

And from firebase docs this one should do the trick

```
const message4 = 'data:text/plain;base64,5b6p5Y+344GX44G+44GX44Gf77yB44GK44KB44Gn44Go44GG77yB';
// This should be message4 = result.assests[0].base64
uploadString(storageRef, message4, 'data_url').then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('Uploaded a data_url string!');
});
```